# \def\foo#1:#2:#3 can be called with \foo{a:b:c} but not \foo{a:\bc}

Tags: macros, tex-core, arguments

This works:

```
\def\myfunc#1{\expandafter\myfuncdoit#1\relax}
\def\myfuncdoit#1:#2:#3\relax{ First: (#1), Second: (#2), Third (#3) }

\foreach \p in {x:foo:int,y:bar:float,z:baz:bool}{ (\myfunc{\p}) }
```

It produces

> First: (x), Second: (foo), Third (int)
>      First: (y), Second: (bar), Third (float)
>      First: (z), Second: (baz), Third (bool)

However, I need to invoke this `\foreach` over a list of *pairs*, with a shared first string:

```
\foreach \p in {foo:int,bar:float,baz:bool}{ (\myfunc{abc:\p}) }
```

I expected this to produce

> First: (abc), Second: (foo), Third (int)
>      First: (abc), Second: (bar), Third (float)
>      First: (abc), Second: (baz), Third (bool)

but it doesn't compile

```
Runaway argument?
float,baz:bool, \pgffor@stop , 
Paragraph ended before \myfuncdoit was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par
```

Why doesn't it work and how do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: You need to expand the argument, otherwise `\myfuncdoit` sees `abc:\p` and doesn't see the second `:` delimiter.

Comment: It does not work because `\p` is not expanded before it is passed to `\myfuncdoit`, only the first token of `#1` is expanded (the `a` of `abc`). If the argument is fully expandable you could use `\edef\reserved@a{#1}\expandafter\myfuncdoit\reserved@a\relax`. But I cannot test this, because unfortunately you have not posted a MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that at the point where the arguments of `\myfuncdoit` are scanned, all separators are in place. No expansion takes place at this moment.

You can do it like that.

```
\newcommand\myfuncx[2]{\myfuncdoit#2:#1\relax}

\foreach \p in {foo:int,bar:float,baz:bool}
  { (\expandafter\myfuncx\expandafter{\p}{abc}) }
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand\myfuncx[2]{\myfuncdoit#2:#1\relax}
\def\myfuncdoit#1:#2:#3\relax{ First: (#1), Second: (#2), Third (#3) }
\begin{document}
\foreach \p in {foo:int,bar:float,baz:bool}
      { (\expandafter\myfuncx\expandafter{\p}{abc}) }
\end{document}
```

Comment: I accepted this answer because it is more concise and requires no libraries, but it bothers me that `{abc}` comes after `{\p}` -- not that it matters except when [I tried to adjust your solution](http://pastebin.com/9cmeDzD7) so that `{abc}` is the first argument, it wouldn't compile.  Am I just being thick or is there a reason you switched the order around?

Comment: @spraff The point is that I want to expand `\p` before expanding `\myfuncx`. `\expandafter` tells TeX to expand the second next token before expanding the next one. So `\expandafter\xxx\expandafter{\yyy` will expand first `\yyy` and only then `\xxx` followed by `{` followed by whatever resulted from the expansion of `\yyy`. If I switch the  order resulting in something like `\xxx{abc}{\yyy}`, then I cannot reach `\yyy` with `\expandafter`s anymore.

Answer (score 1):

An easy extension of my previous answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myfuncthree}{>{\SplitArgument{2}{:}}m}{%
  \myfuncsplitthree#1%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myfuncsplitthree}{mmm}{%
  First: (#1), Second: (#2), Third: (#3).%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\cycle}{ m +m }
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\cycle{foo:int, bar:float, baz:bool}{\myfuncthree{abc:#1}\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you instead call

```
\cycle{foo:int, bar:float, baz:bool}{\myfuncthree{#1:zzz}\par}
```

you get the expected result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `\edef` to expand the argument of `\myfunc`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\def\myfunc#1{\edef\my@tmp{#1}\expandafter\myfuncdoit\my@tmp\relax}
\def\myfuncdoit#1:#2:#3\relax{ First: (#1), Second: (#2), Third (#3) }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\foreach \p in {x:foo:int,y:bar:float,z:baz:bool}{ (\myfunc{\p})\par }
\foreach \p in {foo:int,bar:float,baz:bool}{ (\myfunc{abc:\p})\par }
\end{document}
```